# Transposing a worksheet and sorting to generate two views (original and transposed)

Tags: excel, vba

New workbook opens fine with transposed data copied from original, but executable sorting code does not sort.

Tried various code strings from others based on extensive searches - no examples found that are similar to this effort

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'clear any thing on clipboard to maximize available memory
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'unfreeze all panes
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False

    'copy the data, create new workbook, and paste transposed data into worksheet

    Dim newWB As Workbook, currentWB As Workbook
    Dim newS As Worksheet, currentS As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
    Dim SortRange As Range

    'Copy the data you need
    Set currentWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set currentS = currentWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = currentS.Cells(currentS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = currentS.Cells(2, currentS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy

    'Create a new file that will receive the data and paste it
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    With newWB
        Set newS = newWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
        newS.Activate
        newS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

        'reselect the range to sort and sort

        LastRow = newS.Cells(newS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = newS.Cells(1, newS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
        'newS.Range("A1").Select

        'Apply sort
         With ActiveSheet.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With

    'CODE RUNS TO HERE BUT DOES NOT SORT

    'move back to cell C2 and freeze row and column headings
    Cells(2, 3).Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

    'select all columns and adjust width and height
    ActiveCell.Columns("A:DV").EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 13
    Selection.Rows.AutoFit

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

runs fine through the sort then get a

> Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

on the freezepane code. However, the new transposed data window DOES NOT SORT.

Comment: Please show a portion of sample input, and sample bad output, and sample corrected output as it should be.  What about blank columns with only a header?  Or columns with more rows than column A?  Headers don't seem to be transposed when copy starts at (2,1).

Comment: Change the line `.SetRange Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))` to `SetRange Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))` and sort will work. Could not see any reason why `FreezePanes` gives error. Tried  your code (with makeshift data) and worked without error,. may something related to data etc  However try to avoid `Selects` and `Activates` except in case of Freezing Panes and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code and this should work:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'clear any thing on clipboard to maximize available memory
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'unfreeze all panes
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False

    'copy the data, create new workbook, and paste transposed data into worksheet

    Dim newWB As Workbook, currentWB As Workbook
    Dim newS As Worksheet, currentS As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
    Dim SortRange As Range

    Set currentWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set currentS = currentWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Create a new file that will receive the data
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add    
    Set newS = newWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Copy the data you need
    With currentS
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy
    End With

    'Paste it asap
    With newS
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False        

        'We know we copied LastRow-1 rows, and LastColumn columns
        'So our pasted data is just the other way round. So we just use that info.

        'Apply sort
        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=newS.Range("A1"), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange newS.Range(newS.Cells(1, 1), newS.Cells(LastColumn, LastRow-1))
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With

    'move back to cell C2 (of newS, I assume) and freeze row and column headings
    ' Let us do it without Select :)
    newS.Activate
    With ActiveWindow
        If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False
        .SplitColumn = 2
        .SplitRow = 1
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With

    'adjust width and height of all columns, the right way (with our range)
    With newS.Range(newS.Cells(1, 1), newS.Cells(LastColumn, LastRow-1))
        .ColumnWidth = 13
        .Rows.AutoFit
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Like a Charm!  Thank you!!